# Extremely high ping on just one computer

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet, connection

So, something very weird is happening to me...here are the facts:

- Before I moved to this place, my internet connection was running
  perfectly.
- Changed residence and ISP, internet is very-very slow when loading
  pages, but download speed is as expected ( 1 MB/sec on a 10 Mbps
  bandwidth)
- Finally managed to trick my pc into loading speedtest.net by using
  USB tethering, and my ping using my ISP's connection turned up to be
  10023 ms, download speed around 8 Mbps and upload speed at 0.07 Mbps.
  These results are consistent throughout multiple tests on multiple
  servers. Also, testing my speed using USB tethering showed normal
  results.

Now, the funny part is that I'm the only one in this house experiencing these problems, the rest can firstly open speedtest.net and have a ping of ~20-30 ms.
I've also tried using LAN instead of wireless, but with no change.

Here's the result of ipconfig /all:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Baraulu>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Baraulu-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F4-6D-04-1D-0B-50
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 74-F0-6D-C5-2E-9B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network
Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E0-B9-A5-1F-E4-83
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.13(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 28 April 2012 10:22:52
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 28 April 2012 16:52:13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{0774B6CE-5B19-4520-875D-4100D0BC09C6}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:1800:f46:3f57:fef2(Prefe
rred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1800:f46:3f57:fef2%14(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Also, by using inSSIDer, I can see that there are no other wireless networks broadcasting on the same channels as my router is using.

Any ideas/solutions are highly welcome as I have absolutely no idea why this is happening..

Comment: Some thoughts: The way to diagnose this is to look at the network configs of the computers that are not seeing 10 second ping times and see where they differ from yours.  "home" as a DNS search suffix doesn't look right to me.  Stupendously long ping times are usually a side effect of DNS lookup problems, but they could also due to throttling / packet-shaping at your router or at your ISP.

Answer (score 3):

I have a really similar problem but I was told that it might be malware etc and i checked with malwareBytes, bitDefender and other anti virus programs.

But I'm still having this issue, I have one other computer in the same network which shows no problems related to this.

I even tried to boot this computer in safe mode and the problem goes away.

I've suspicious that it might be a web traffic filtering virus that somehow delays my internet connection (only http or https) because in some games I play the ping is like 50 ms but in http traffic ping goes like 1900 ms which is nuts.

My internet is supposed to be 4 mbps but in this computer i only get 2 mbps downloaod and 0.10 uploaod which is crazy considering my other computer connected to the same modem gets 0.60 mbps upload.

By the way this started about a month or two ago.

Comment: If i do a pingtest.net I get normal delays like 15 or 20 ms totally different what speedtest.net says, but when I surf on the internet i can notice the lag specially in sites with lots of images, again this is just in the first computer in the second one i have none of this problems.

Comment: I finally resolved the issue deactivating bitdefender 2011 and installed 2012 although i had to disable http traffic monitoring.